# Hot reloading running PHP script?

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

My architecture is composed of the following :

A `supervisor` controller that makes sure n instances of the same PHP scripts are running (and restart them when there are not).

The script is a `while` loop that waits for a job from `Beanstalk` and process it when it arrive. After a certain number of loops (defined), the script exit, in order to be reloaded by supervisorctl (I do that because PHP tends to be instable in the long run).

When I push some changes, I have to wait that the "workers" have finished the number of expected loop to be restarted and then take into consideration the new changes.

Is there a way to fasten this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: While not really useful, as you've found PHP doesn't really seem the best choice for this, so I suppose my suggestion would be to use a language better suited for the task. Probably one of the event based ones.

Comment: I don't think an other language is relevant here, because if I use a better suited language, it will be worse in my case : the script will never restart because it's too much efficient ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simply decoupling the loop from the code that ingest the jobs + using process control extension can help, check this out: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/1/8/running-programs-in-the-current-process-space

(Sorry if I'm making wrong assumptions here, I don't have enough Karma to ask questions through comments)

Comment: The idea to use an external script is really interesting. Since I'm already using PHP as shell scripts, it does make sense. By the way, welcome to the community :)

Comment: *"I don't have enough Karma to ask questions through comments"* - You have 86, and is enough to comment ;-) 50+ is needed for it.